# How to deal with KeyErrors correctly

Tags: django

As a newbie to Django I'm still learning the ropes my question below is not to do with syntax directly but the best approach.

How would you handle something like below when no value is passed in the url. I get an error.

```
  cat_id = self.request.GET.get('cat_id', '')
        return Product.objects.filter(category=cat_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

cat_id = self.request.GET.get('cat_id', '')

# 404 if the category deosn't exist
category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=cat_id)

# filter for products based on a known existing category
products = Product.objects.filter(category=category)
```

In other contexts I might do something like this

```
if 'cat_id' in self.request.GET:
    cat_id = self.request.GET.get('cat_id')
    # now do stuff with cat_id
```

Comment: but then Product.objects.filter(category=cat_id) will give an error will it not?

Comment: we only want to fetch products if a valid category id is sent over. So, first we try to load a category object using the id from the GET.  filter can either filter based on id's or on objects, If we need to make sure the object exists, we may as well load it.

Comment: also, just noticed, if using the ID in the filter, assuming cat_id is the category ID of the Category model the filter should be: `Product.objects.filter(category__pk=cat_id)`

Answer (score 1):

Use 0 as default value instead of empty string.

Comment: but then if will try and filter by the value 0 if not value is passed. I want to not filter at all if no value is passed.